# Pulling and Pushing Repo

Tags: java, git, github, push, pull

I am very new to using Github. I am only used to writing code in my local device. I need to pull a repo off of github, create a new file inside of the repo (Which will have my .java program), and push it back to github. I have looked online but the explanations are pretty confusing to me (As a beginner).

Comment: Looks like you are also new to google? https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: I would advise you first to have a look on SO git documentation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check to make sure you have git installed locally first:

   Run in your command line:

   ```
   git --version
   ```
2. If it returns a git version, then go to the github repository and copy the path like so:

   [image]
3. In your command line type `git clone` followed by the path (paste it in) like so:

   From the above example:

   [image]
4. Press return or enter. The repository will be cloned and set up for you locally.
5. After the cloning is finished, you can `cd` directly into the repository. In the above example I would type:

   ```
   cd cordova-runner
   ```
6. Assuming you have been given contributor rights from the repository's owner, you can from there make changes, branch, add, commit, and push back to the repository. If you haven't been given rights, you can do the same process, but fork the repo first.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the git command line tool:
https://git-scm.com/downloads

If you're on windows, there's a git bash many people prefer over cmd.  On any other operating system, just use the terminal/cli.

Once installed, first you'll want to clone the repository.  You'll find the URL on the repository page after clicking the green "Clone or download" button:

```
git clone [url]
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Then you'll add your file to be tracked by git:

```
git add [filename]
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Then you'll commit your changes.

```
git commit -m "Added a file like a champ!"
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Then you'll push your changes, provided you have permissions to push.

```
git push [remote name] [branch]
```

Use `git remote -v` to view your remote names and URLs.  Your remote name is default "origin" at first so if your branch name is "develop," it would be `git push origin develop`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

The alternative, and the correct way to do it, is to fork the repo, make your changes, commit and push your changes to your remote repo, then create a pull request on the original repo's branch:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/

Pull requests are requesting the other person pull your changes into their branch.  This gets into merging and such:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

I provided documentation links in an effort to persuade you to check them out.  Both github and git provide excellent documentation.  There are also countless git tutorials online, many are interactive and really help you learn this brand of source control.

Answer (score 0):

Git clone <--Url to repository-->

Git checkout <--branchname-->

Create your file

Git pull (to again sync the repo with remote repo)

Git add

Git commit -m "write comment here"

Git push

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is

```
svn co https://github.com/path/to/repo
... create your new file ...
svn add your_file
svn commit your_file -m "Message about new file."
```

and then you're done.

Comment: Git, not SVN. They are both different entities.

Comment: Github works with SVN. https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support

Comment: But, it is not the preferred option.

Comment: Irrelevant. Its the easier option.